# Twitter Bootstrap icons not working with Amazon S3 and Heroku (using asset_sync gem)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, heroku, amazon-s3, icons, twitter-bootstrap

I started using the [asset_sync gem in order to use Amazon S3 as a CDN asset host](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31) (I am using Heroku and RoR). All of my assets are loading correctly, except for the icons I am using through Twitter Bootstrap (There is just a blank space where the icon should be).

I tried using Heroku's multiple asset pre-processor support:

*app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss.erb*

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path "../img/glyphicons-halflings.png"%>);
```

I also tried moving the glyphicons-halflings.png directly into the images folder and referencing it there:

*app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss.erb*

```
background-image: url(<%= asset_path "/assets/glyphicons-halflings.png"%>);
```

*app/assets/stylesheets/custom.css.scss*

```
background-image: url("/assets/glyphicons-halflings.png");
```

However, I've haven't found a way to make it work. Any suggestions on how to get the Twitter Bootstrap icons to work successfully with S3/Heroku would be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** I am using: `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 2.0.2'`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `gem 'bootstrap-sass'`, the following is a solution that worked for me.

First, download bootstrap from the [bootstrap website](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/). Extract the two icon .png files (glyphicons-halflings.png and glyphicons-halflings-white.png) and copy them into your apps image directory (app/images).

In your custom.css.scss file (this could be a different name depending on your app) enter the following at the top of your stylesheet (before you import bootstrap) to override the icon image path:

```
 $iconSpritePath: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings.png');
 $iconWhiteSpritePath: url('/assets/glyphicons-halflings-white.png');

 @import "bootstrap";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the Rails image helper for example:

```
background-image: image-url("glyphicons-halflings.png");
```

You can also check your search path in the Rails console with:

```
Rails.application.config.assets.paths
```

Good luck!

Comment: The path for the gem is "/Users/myusername/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/bootstrap-sass-2.0.2/vendor/assets/images". So how should I reference this in my CSS file to get the icons to work? I tried dropping the .png file in my images folder and using the Rails image helper as you suggested, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Have you set your asset host?

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cdn-asset-host-rails31#configuration

Comment: Hi Neil, thanks for the suggestion. Yes, I have set the asset host.  My images and backgrounds are all loading fine off of S3, it is only the icons that are not loading for me.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check the background-image URL that is actually used? I had the same behavior when I tried to test the CDN in my development enviroment. Turns out, somehow the wrong bucket was used in the application.css

Answer (score 0):

For anyone not using the bootstrap-sass gem I finally got mine working by changing the default bootstrap css file extension to scss and editing the following piece of code to use the rails `asset_url` method. Just search for @font-face in the code and try this.

```
@font-face {
 font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';

 src: asset_url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot');
 src: asset_url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), asset_url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff') format('woff'), asset_url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), asset_url('glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular') format('svg');
}
```

Commit and push to heroku. Worked for me. Hope this helps someone